# create embedding metadata in the setup.exe after it's build

Tags: python-2.7, nsis

I have create setup.exe using NSIS not i want to embeded metadata once the setup is create is their a way to create it in nsis or i need something else. Is there a package in python which allow me to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append data to the .exe in any format you want and then use the NSIS `File*` instructions to read from yourself (`$EXEPATH`).

If you want to embed a string you can prefix it with a special like "CUSTDATA:" and use [this function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) to read the data in the installer.

Comment: Thanks mate, I am new nsis and unable to understand the example could please give me an working example of custdata that will help me......